# How can i add second resource adapter to work with ibm mq (WebSphere) and ActiveMQ (Artemis) at the same time?

Tags: java, wildfly, ibm-mq, activemq-artemis, java-ee-8

1. I want use ActiveMQ (Artemis) and IBM MQ at the same time.
2. ActiveMQ built-in Wildfly Application Server where was deployed my application.
3. I want use two resource adapters, first for ActiveMQ and second for IBM MQ, but I can not configure it.
4. Here is my configuration for `standalone-full.xml` :

```
 <mdb>
        <resource-adapter-ref resource-adapter-name="${ejb.resource-adapter-name:activemq-ra.rar}"/>
        <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="mdb-strict-max-pool" />
      </mdb>
<resource-adapters>

        <resource-adapter id="wmq.jmsra.rar">
          <archive>wmq.jmsra-9.1.2.0.rar</archive>
          <transaction-support>NoTransaction</transaction-support>
          <config-property name="startupRetryCount">1</config-property>
          <connection-definitions>
            <connection-definition class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl" jndi-name="java:jboss/jms/ivt/IVTCF" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" pool-name="IVTCF">
              <config-property name="channel">A.CHANNEL01</config-property>
              <config-property name="hostName">any-host</config-property>
              <config-property name="transportType">1</config-property>
              <config-property name="queueManager">QMANAG</config-property>
              <config-property name="port">1415</config-property>
            </connection-definition>
          </connection-definitions>
          <admin-objects>
            <admin-object class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.MQQueueProxy" jndi-name="java:jboss/TEST.Q" pool-name="TEST.REQ">
              <config-property name="baseQueueName">TEST.Q</config-property>
              <config-property name="baseQueueManagerName">QMANAG</config-property>
            </admin-object>
          </admin-objects>
        </resource-adapter>
      </resource-adapters>
```

5. How can I add second adapter here?
6. If I replace:

```
<resource-adapter-ref resource-adapter-name="${ejb.resource-adapter-name:activemq-ra.rar}"/>
```

with

```
<resource-adapter-ref resource-adapter-name="wmq.jmsra.rar"/>
```

my mdb-bean for IBM MQ work well, but mdb-beans for ActiveMQ doesn`t work.

Comment: thanks! for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `resource-adapter-ref` that you're configuring is for the *default* resource adapter to be used by all MDBs which don't specify their own resource adapter configuration. Your MDBs can use whatever resource adapter they want, you just need to configure it, e.g.:

1. At deployment descriptor level

```
<jboss xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:jee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:mdb="urn:resource-adapter-binding"
    xmlns:security="urn:security">

    <jee:assembly-descriptor>
        <mdb:resource-adapter-binding>
            <jee:ejb-name>SOCKET_MDB</jee:ejb-name>
            <mdb:resource-adapter-name>wmq.jmsra.rar</mdb:resource-adapter-name>
        </mdb:resource-adapter-binding>
    </jee:assembly-descriptor>
</jboss>
```

This is a sample `jboss-ejb3.xml` file which can be deployed along with your EJB.

2. Annotate it in your MDB

Another option is by using the `@ResourceAdapter` annotation within your MDB:

```
@MessageDriven(
activationConfig = { 
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="destination", propertyValue="foo")})
@ResourceAdapter(value="wmq.jmsra.rar")
public class MyMDB implements MessageListener {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {        
    }
}
```